# How to see the progress of rsync's receiving and building file lists?

Tags: networking, debian, fedora, rsync

I was trying to use rsync to move over a TB of files from one device on my gigabit LAN to the machine I am on and wanted to be able to see the progress of rsync.
from my machine (fedora 31) I started off with:

```
rsync -avhc -stats --no-i-r --info=progress2 --remove-source-files zorp@192.168.1.101:/mnt/md0/dirs/* .
```

When using the above line it has stayed at "receiving file list ..." for over a day now, I assume because my little NAS (which is running a Debian bare bones installation) is trying to calc checksums for over a TB of files which is ok but I really wanted to have an idea of how far along it is, the progress its making, in terms of calculating those checksums - as it is now it could be totally hung for all i know.

I have tried combinations of the line above adding in -P and -vv and --partial --progress along with taking out things like -stats --info=progress2 though from what i read in the man page it didnt seem like taking those out should make a difference but i am stumped. When I add -P it does give me "to-chk=N/NN" but thats after it sat "building file list ..."

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `--progress` or `-P` option which show progress during file transfer. The syntax is as follows:

```
rsync --progress source dest
rsync -P source dest
rsync [options] --progress source dest
```

You are trying `--info=progress2`, which only works on latest version of rsync.

Try again and I hope it will work fine. :)

Comment: Thank you for that, I tried using -c --progress and -cP without any other parameters and it just said skipping, then I added -a as well (-ac --progress and -acP) and it gave a new response "sending incremental file list" which sounded good but then again it stayed there until it actually started sending the file, no indication while it was (i guess) making/sending the list. So it seems i am back to trying to get an idea of how long the "file list" will take be it incremental, sending, or receiving?

Comment: @DrZog If you didn't saw **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/609495/1103062)**, I would say: give it a chance. I think it is different method, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that, took awhile to digest but I'm afraid that all the options still dont seem to indicate the progress of the different "file list" processes (receiving/sending/making/etc?). All the options seem to show the progress of the actual transfer of files - but I am stuck waiting on the part before the files start transferring. Maybe its just not possible? :/

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that for the "file list" part there just is not an option in rsync that can tell you how far along rsync it with the file list (be it sending, receiving, making etc). Perhaps there is a way in combination with another command but I havent been able to figure that out.

Comment: You can try [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/441724/582722) and answer bellow it. And can you please provide your rsync version by typing `rsync --version`?